# Calculate the VWAP indicator on a daily basis from a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have stocks data in a Dataframe ( Example below)

I'm used to calculate the VWAP  (volume weighted average price with this formula) in this way:

```py
v = df['Volume'].values
tp = (df['Low'] + df['Close'] + df['High']).div(3).values
df = df.assign(vwap=((tp * v).cumsum() / v.cumsum()))
```

Problem is this formula calculation takes the whole Dataframe data into consideration

I want it to be a daily basis (I have multiple values per day and multiple days) , so basically what I want is like cutting the dataframe into separate dataframes based on the date , then running the formula , the adding the dataframes back together so that the calculations only takes into consideration the data from 1 day at a time.

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume                      
2022-05-02 09:30:00-04:00,43.95,44.38,43.50,44.34,44.34,9541433
2022-05-02 10:30:00-04:00,44.34,44.58,43.86,43.97,43.97,5479663
2022-05-02 11:30:00-04:00,43.97,44.33,43.86,44.23,44.23,2892229
2022-05-02 12:30:00-04:00,44.22,44.35,43.72,43.80,43.80,5195766
2022-05-02 13:30:00-04:00,43.80,43.88,43.59,43.66,43.66,3987240
2022-05-02 14:30:00-04:00,43.66,44.63,43.65,44.56,44.56,4862374
2022-05-02 15:30:00-04:00,44.56,44.99,44.54,44.95,44.95,8261432
2022-05-03 09:30:00-04:00,44.79,44.95,44.22,44.80,44.80,7973069
2022-05-03 10:30:00-04:00,44.80,45.04,44.47,44.96,44.96,4656776
2022-05-03 11:30:00-04:00,44.96,45.18,44.83,44.90,44.90,6341864
2022-05-03 12:30:00-04:00,44.90,45.47,44.84,45.38,45.38,3948134
2022-05-03 13:30:00-04:00,45.38,45.49,44.99,45.00,45.00,2851084
2022-05-03 14:30:00-04:00,45.00,45.27,44.75,45.09,45.09,4262658
2022-05-03 15:30:00-04:00,45.09,45.21,44.94,45.06,45.06,6663177
2022-05-04 09:30:00-04:00,45.16,45.25,44.75,44.80,44.80,6153218
2022-05-04 10:30:00-04:00,44.80,45.0,44.56,44.61,44.61,3298989 
2022-05-04 11:30:00-04:00,44.61,45.09,44.40,45.00,45.00,3512521
2022-05-04 12:30:00-04:00,45.00,45.29,44.95,45.15,45.15,2959304
2022-05-04 13:30:00-04:00,45.15,45.61,45.0,45.38,45.38,5924683 
2022-05-04 14:30:00-04:00,45.38,46.52,44.79,46.49,46.49,9963984
2022-05-04 15:30:00-04:00,46.50,46.63,46.39,46.54,46.54,7398220
2022-05-05 09:30:00-04:00,45.59,45.90,45.25,45.43,45.43,6109166
2022-05-05 10:30:00-04:00,45.43,45.72,45.25,45.31,45.31,4406271
2022-05-05 11:30:00-04:00,45.31,45.56,44.99,45.33,45.33,4426484
```

Comment: Look at the ```groupby``` function. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 0):

You first group by day, `df.Date.dt.date` will give you the day. Then you just apply your vwap function to the daily group you just created. I corrected your vwap function so it is more elegant (and efficient).

```py
def vwap(g):
   g['vwap'] = (g.tp * g.Volume).cumsum() / g.Volume.cumsum()
   return g

df['tp'] = (df['Low'] + df['Close'] + df['High']) / 3
df = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.date).apply(vwap)
df
```

Comment: it worked thanks :D
if you have time please explain the logic so I can do this on my own next time

Answer (score 0):

The logic is really simple. You just group the data by date. Then you apply the function vwap to each grouped dataframe which is the original dataframe grouped by day.
The function looks for the column tp and Volume and returns the dataframe with additional column.